# Pygame: item in pygame.sprite.Group() has no attribute rect

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, rect, pygame-surface

I am new to Python and got stuck with some Pygame code (see below traceback and complete code). I don't understand why the bullet object has no rect attribute when I iterate over the items stored in self.bullets. Any help or pointers would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

**Traceback**

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/svengerlach/PycharmProjects/AlienInvasion/practice_12_6.py", line 82, in <module>
>     game.game_loop()
>   File "/Users/svengerlach/PycharmProjects/AlienInvasion/practice_12_6.py", line 22, in game_loop
>     self._bullet_update()
>   File "/Users/svengerlach/PycharmProjects/AlienInvasion/practice_12_6.py", line 54, in _bullet_update
>     if bullet.rect.left > self.screen_rect.right:
> AttributeError: 'Bullet' object has no attribute 'rect'
> ```

**Complete Code**

```
import pygame
import sys


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        [...]
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def game_loop(self):
        while True:
            self._check_user_inputs()
            self._ship_update()
            self._bullet_update()
            self._screen_update()

    def _check_user_inputs(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                [...]
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    new_bullet = Bullet(self)
                    self.bullets.add(new_bullet)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                [...]

    def _ship_update(self):
        [...]

    def _bullet_update(self):
        self.bullets.update()
        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.left > self.screen_rect.right:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)

    def _screen_update(self):
        [...]
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        pygame.display.flip()


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.ship_rect = ai_game.ship_rect
        self.bullet_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 15, 3)
        self.bullet_rect.midleft = self.ship_rect.midright

    def update(self):
        self.bullet_rect.x += 5

    def draw_bullet(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (60, 60, 60), self.bullet_rect)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.game_loop()
```

Comment: `bullet` has no attribute `rect`, because it has an attribute `bullet_rect`. Anyway I recommend to rename `bullet_rect` to `rect` rather than `rect` to `bullet_rect`. See [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bullet` has no attribute `rect`, but it has an attribute `bullet_rect`. I recommend to rename `bullet_rect` to `rect`. This way you can use [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect` for the position.

Furthermore use [`pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill):

> The Sprite is removed from all the Groups that contain it. [...]

Example:

```py
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((15, 3))
        self.image.fill((60, 60, 60))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midleft = ai_game.ship_rect.midright)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += 5
```

```py
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        # [...]
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def game_loop(self):
        while True:
            self._check_user_inputs()
            self._ship_update()
            self._bullet_update()
            self._screen_update()

    def _check_user_inputs(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                # [...]
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    self.bullets.add(Bullet(self))
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                # [...]

    def _bullet_update(self):
        self.bullets.update()
        for bullet in self.bullets:
            if bullet.rect.left > self.screen_rect.right:
                bullet.kill()

    def _screen_update(self):
        # [...]
        self.bullets.draw(ai_game.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
```